# How to display a text in from a texfield at the same time it is being typed in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am trying to build a custom widget where it has a texfield and a Text widget where the Text widget displays the text in the texfield while the user is typing. Tried to use OnChanged of texfield but only display when the widget is refreshed.

Comment: You could setup a TextEditingController as the controller of that textfield. Use its `text` property to get the text

Comment: This will only work after sumbissioor hot reload not while the user is typing

Comment: Are you using a `StatelessWidget`? Because on `StatefulWidget` it should work without hot reload/restart